# C++ using vector as static container for class instances

Tags: c++, vector

I use a vector as static member of a class to count all the instance of the class itself and its derived classes. However When trying to resize the container I get a stack-overflow thrown from the vector itself.

```
 // initialize static values:
    auto_ptr<HandleManager> ID3OBJ::HM = auto_ptr<HandleManager>(new HandleManager());
    auto_ptr<vector<shared_ptr<ID3OBJ>>> ID3OBJ::ObjectList = auto_ptr<vector<shared_ptr<ID3OBJ>>>(new vector<shared_ptr<ID3OBJ>>{});
```

I initialize the static member as empty as shown above.

```
// constructors:
        ID3OBJ::ID3OBJ(double x, double y, double z) : X(x), Y(y), Z(z), Handle(this->HM->addHandle()) { ObjectList->push_back(auto_ptr<ID3OBJ>(this));}
        ID3OBJ::ID3OBJ() : X(0), Y(0), Z(0), Handle(this->HM->addHandle()) { ObjectList->push_back(shared_ptr<ID3OBJ>(this));}

        Vector::Vector(double x, double y, double z) { X = x; Y = y; Z = z;
        ObjectList->push_back(auto_ptr<Vector>(this));}
        Vector::Vector() {
            X = 0; Y = 0; Z = 0;
            ObjectList->push_back(shared_ptr<Vector>(this));}
```

The constructors add any new instance to the instancelist, which is called ObjectList. This is working as intended.

```
// deconstructors:
    ID3OBJ::~ID3OBJ()
    {
        string tempH = this->Handle;
        auto iter = ObjectList->end();
        if (ObjectList->size() == HM->assignedHandles())
        {
            iter = remove_if(ObjectList->begin(), ObjectList->end(), [&](shared_ptr<ID3OBJ> ptr) {return ptr->getHandle() == tempH; });
        }
        ObjectList->erase(iter, ObjectList->end());
        this->HM->removeHandle(this->Handle);
    }

    Vector::~Vector()
    {
        string tempH = this->Handle;
        auto iter = ObjectList->end();
        if (ObjectList->size() == HM->assignedHandles())
        {
            iter=remove_if(ObjectList->begin(), ObjectList->end(), [&](shared_ptr<ID3OBJ> ptr) {return ptr->getHandle() == tempH; });
        }
        ObjectList->erase(iter, ObjectList->end());
    }
```

As far as I understand remove_if replaces any occurances whose pred returns true with the element after the occurance. Means if the pred with vec[3] as argument returns true, vec[2] points to vec[4] instead of vec[3].
Hence the erase function is needed to shorten the container length, however as soon as I implement this shortening an error occurs.

Header File:

```
// class-name:      ID3OBJ
    // Date:            30.01.2017
    // Version:         1.0
    // Description:     The class works as base class for all used 3D-Objects, and defines the operations all 3D-Objects have, namely the Direction in case of a vector, or origion in all other cases
    //

    class ID3OBJ
    {
    public:
        double X;
        double Y;
        double Z;
        static auto_ptr<vector<shared_ptr<ID3OBJ>>> ObjectList;

        ID3OBJ(double x, double y, double z);
        ID3OBJ();
        ~ID3OBJ();
        const string getHandle();

    protected:
        string Handle;
        static auto_ptr<HandleManager> HM;
    };

    // class-name:      I3DM
    // Date:            23.03.2017
    // Version:         1.0
    // Description:     The class works as Interface for classes which can do Vector-operations 
    //
    template <class T> class I3DM : public virtual ID3OBJ
    {
    public:
        using ID3OBJ::X;
        using ID3OBJ::Y;
        using ID3OBJ::Z;

        static auto_ptr<vector<shared_ptr<T>>> ObjectList;
    protected:
        using ID3OBJ::Handle;
        using ID3OBJ::HM;
    };
    // class-name:      Vector
    // Date:            30.01.2017
    // Version:         1.0
    // Description:     The class works as vector, it provides an interface to acces and modify vectors, aswell as most of the vector operations
    //
    class Vector : public virtual I3DM<Vector>
    { 
    public:
        using I3DM<Vector>::X;
        using I3DM<Vector>::Y;
        using I3DM<Vector>::Z;
        using I3DM<Vector>::ObjectList;
        Vector(double x, double y, double z);
        Vector();
        ~Vector();
    //I'm not sure if the protected members have to be provided aswell in the header file
    protected:
        using ID3OBJ::Handle;
        using ID3OBJ::HM;
    };
```

HM-header:

```
class HandleManager
    {
    public:
        HandleManager();
        const int assignedHandles();
        const string addHandle();
        void removeHandle(string hexstring);
    protected:
        int AssignedHandles;
        forward_list<int> FreeHandles;
        bool FreeHandlesAvailable;
    };
```

CPP:

```
const int string_to_hex(string s)
{
    int returnvalue;
    stringstream stream;
    stream << hex << s;
    stream >> returnvalue;
    return returnvalue;
}
HandleManager::HandleManager()
{
    this->FreeHandlesAvailable = false;
    this->AssignedHandles = 0;
}
const int HandleManager::assignedHandles()
{
    return this->AssignedHandles;
}
const string HandleManager::addHandle()
{
    string returnValue;
    if (this->FreeHandlesAvailable)
    {
        returnValue = int_to_hex(this->FreeHandles.front());
        this->FreeHandles.pop_front();
        this->AssignedHandles++;
        if (this->FreeHandles.empty()) { this->FreeHandlesAvailable = false; }
    }
    else
    {
        returnValue = int_to_hex(this->AssignedHandles);
        this->AssignedHandles++;
        if (this->AssignedHandles == 1) { returnValue = int_to_hex((int)0); }
        }
    return returnValue;
}
void HandleManager::removeHandle(string hexstring)
{
    this->FreeHandlesAvailable = true;
    this->FreeHandles.push_front(string_to_hex(hexstring));
    this->AssignedHandles--;
}
```

error message:

> Unhandled exception at 0x00C01899 in RVE.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow (parameters: 0x00000001, 0x01002F48). occurred

The parameter 0x00000001 is most likely a handle, is there any way to search for the object which has the memory adress given? (0x01002F48)

Comment: Using `std::auto_ptr` was never encouraged. It also have been deprecated since the C++11 standard, and are removed in the C++17 standard..

Comment: Okay, so I ll have to use a regular pointer and clean it up after using, but I doubt this has anything to do with my error

Comment: @Y.S Or use `std::unique_ptr` instead.

Comment: The "minimal" aspect of your [mcve] could use some work.

Comment: Shouldn't you get a stack trace when exception is thrown? Also you seem to store different kinds of smart pointers into the same container: `ObjectList->push_back(auto_ptr<Vector>(this));` and `ObjectList->push_back(shared_ptr<Vector>(this));`. Does this even compiler? Also there is no need to "use vector as static member of a class to count all the instance of the class itself and its derived classes", just `size_t` would be sufficient for this purpose.

Comment: @VTT Most stack overflow errors don't cause a trace. If the stack is overflowed, its integrity is dubious.

Comment: @VTT: I am not counting, I am storing pointers to the instances to make sure each pointer is only existing once. The wished pointer can be selected using the current handle, hence I have no duplicate pointers to instances later :) - thinking of this, this should be shared_ptr and not auto_ptr ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider what happens when you remove an `ID3OBJ` from the vector:

1. The vector will destroy the `auto_ptr<ID3OBJ>`...
2. Which will try to destroy the `ID3OBJ`...
3. Whose destructor will try to remove the `auto_ptr<ID3OBJ>` from the vector...
4. Which will destroy the `auto_ptr<ID3OBJ>`... and we go back to step 1.

This process will recurse until the stack is overflowed.  The same is true for the `Vector` vector too.  (Roger, Roger. What's your vector, Victor?)

The standard library `vector` is not designed to be re-entrant; if a member of `vector` winds up calling itself, the behavior is undefined. In your case, `vector::erase()` indirectly calls itself through your destructors.

Therefore, your program's behavior is undefined.

Comment: Thank you for explaining the behaviour, I will add a solution to fix this later to my question :)

Answer (score 1):

auto_ptr<..>(this), shared_ptr<..>(this) or unique_ptr<..>(this) is never correct and a bug waiting to happen. Smart pointers take values from *allocated* memory, **this** is pointer to an object and you do not know how it came about. You are effectively doing something like the following,

```
int a;
auto_ptr< int > ap0( &a );   // certain death.
shared_ptr< int > ap1( &a ); // also certain death.
```

or equally bad,

```
auto_ptr< int > ap( new int );
auto_ptr< int > ap0( ap.get() );   // certain death.
shared_ptr< int > ap1( ap.get() ); // also certain death.
```

It is hard to understand what you are trying to achieve. If you simply want to track instances your vector should definitely be raw pointers. If your purpose is memory management, then I can't see how this could work from your code.

Comment: I am using auto_ptr since it will deconstruct automatically if it's not used anymore, hence I don't have to worry about the cleanup of the vector inside it. The vector is initiated using new to make sure enough memory is available ;)
I have to add `this` since I want a pointer to the new generated object,and I need a shared pointer since the pointers will be used by various other objects.
Could you please explain me why your example will lead to certain death? My example does initiate the object before passing it, so it would be: `int a = 5; shared_ptr<int> ap0(&a);`

Comment: The problem is that the smart pointer will call `delete  &a;` but `&a` is not memory allocated by a call to `new`. Smart pointers are not for storing every pointer, only pointers that are allocated from heap memory (i.e. using `new`. )